# 2^power without using math.pow and multiplication

Tags: c++

Is there any way to use code 2^power without using math.pow or multiplication operator.
So far,

I've though of using 2 counters and additions, but my programs doesn't seem to be working. Here is my work thus far.

```
int counter=0; // k 
int userNumber=0; // p 
int power=0;
int sum=0;

cout << "Enter a non-negative number: ";
cin >> userNumber;


while (userNumber > counter)
{
    power +=2;
    counter++;
    power++;
}

sum = power - 1;
// post-condition: Sum = 2^p -1
cout << "The output is " << sum << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: Is this an interview question? Or homework? The reason why I'm asking, we have exactly that question on our job interview. There's a really simple answer based on a relatively obscure C++ feature, but if you're supposed to guess for yourself...

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I dare say you need to come up with more insightful interview questions. ;-)

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people flunk this. Also, [remember the FizzBuzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html).

Comment: I'd hire any programmer that doesn't get that one right just to be able to fire him or her the following second. Now getting the fine differences right about dividing by 2 and bit shifts, that'd be something else.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Why is it important exactly to ask about _obscure_ language dependent "features" on an interview?

Comment: To see if the candidate learned it formally or by copy-pasting others' code.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
   pow = 1;
   while(userNumber > counter){
        pow = pow+pow;
        counter++;
   }
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now; This makes so much sense! Thanks you SOOO much!!

Comment: @Namen: It seems that you didn't like any of the bit-shift answers. Was there a reason for this?

Comment: This looks more like an attempt to calculate 2*userNumber, not 2^userNumber.  And since power is initialized to zero, this always generates zero.

Comment: @IronMensan This program generates 2^userNumber. In each loop pow is 2^counter because 2^n = (2^(n-1) + 2^(n-1)).

Comment: You edited it 3 minutes before leaving that comment. Not cool, it was a horrible failure when first posted.

Answer (score 79):

You can calculate `2^n` with bit-manipulation. Simply do:

```
1 << n;
```

This works because left-shifting with binary numbers is equivalent to multiplying by 2.

Comment: +1 for 2k, now you won't have to get permission for your edits anymore. :)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `ldexp` function.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young As is math.pow(). The problem seems actually much more interesting for FP than int (I mean for int that's trivial really)

Comment: I assumed we were generalizing to floating point, given that math.pow was given as an option. And because the integer case is uninteresting.